# On perturbation theory simulation in quantum physics

Tags: python, simulation, physics

I have started a python course and am constantly looking out for opportunity to develop codes of any kind. Recently came across a standard physics problem that can be simulated in python to demonstrate energy spectrum due to perturbation. Here is the statement:

There is a quantum particle of mass m that is bound inside a 2-D square box of length 'l'. Assume that the box has finite rigidity.
(Hint : You can define the origin of the xy plane on one corner of your box and the edges along the x and y axes.)

a) Obtain the energy eigenvalues  and eigenfunctions.  Plot the first three eigenfunctions and clearly mention any degeneracies.

b) Say the box is perturbed by a weak potential V(x,y) = V_0*x*y. Nnow calculate the change in the ground state energy, and the splitting in the first excited state.

c) Plot the approximate  perturbed energy eigenfunction for the first  excited state.

Finally, show what the energy spectrum would look like before and after the small perturbation.

I just need some ideas to only get started with this. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You mean something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmC0ygr08tE ?

Comment: Or this https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/09/05/quantum-python/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a very simple Python program. Just define the wavefunction for the square-well as a Python function along with a function for its energy eigenvalues, plugin known constants, and plot the result. For example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def psi(x, n, a):
    assert(n != 0)
    return np.sqrt(2/a)*np.sin(n*np.pi*x/a)

L = 100
hbar = 6.626e-34 # joule seconds
m = 1e-19 # kg
x = np.arange(1, L)
y1 = np.array([psi(xi, 1, L) for xi in x])
y2 = np.array([psi(xi, 2, L) for xi in x])
y3 = np.array([psi(xi, 3, L) for xi in x])

plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.plot(x,y3)
plt.show()

def k(n, a):
    assert(n != 0)
    return n*np.pi/a

def E(n, a, m):
    return (hbar**2)*(k(n, a)**2)/(2*m)

E1 = E(1, L, m)
E2 = E(2, L, m)
E3 = E(3, L, m)
```

Assuming you understand the physics, the rest should be easy. A good reference is [Introduction to Quantum Mechanics by Griffiths](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Quantum_Mechanics.html?id=0h-nDAAAQBAJ).